# BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE notification is not getting called with CMFCButton class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE notification code is not getting called with CMFCButton class.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Steps performed:

1) Add a CButton to my dialog from the resource editor.

2) Use my own derived class CMFCButtonEx derived from CMFCButton class (which in turn is derived from CButton class).

3) Declare CMFCButtonEx 'm_btn_ex' instance variable to my dialog.

4) Add DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON_EX, m_btn_ex);

5) When I click this button all my message handlers in the derived class are called except BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE notification associated with OnButtonItemChange function. The breakpoint in that function never hits. All the other message handlers (OnMouseMove, OnMouseLeave, and OnButtonClicked) are called correctly, and the breakpoints in them get hit.

As a note if I derive by CMFCButtonEx class from CButton class, then I can hit the breakpoint in OnButtonItemChange function i.e. BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE notification code is handled correctly

For some reason my BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE notification code is not being handled correctly by CMFCButton class. I can't understand what am I doing wrong here. I have also tried to use TBN_HOTITEMCHANGE notification code instead of BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE but the breakpoint in the OnButtonItemChange function never hits.

Thanks!

CMFCButtonEx class code:

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMFCButtonEx, CMFCButton)
CMFCButtonEx::CMFCButtonEx()
{   
     m_bMouseTracking = FALSE    
}

CMFCButtonEx::~CMFCButtonEx()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCButtonEx, CMFCButton)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMFCButtonEx)
    ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
    ON_WM_MOUSELEAVE()
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX(BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE, OnButtonItemChange)
   //ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX(TBN_HOTITEMCHANGE, OnButtonItemChange)
    ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX(BN_CLICKED, OnButtonClicked)  
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CMFCButtonEx::OnButtonClicked()
{
    AfxMessageBox("MFC Button Clicked");
    return FALSE;
}

BOOL CMFCButtonEx::OnButtonItemChange(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMBCHOTITEM* pnmbchotitem = (NMBCHOTITEM*)pNMHDR;

    AfxMessageBox("MFC Button Item Change");

    *pResult = 0;
    return FALSE;
}

void CMFCButtonEx::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    if (!m_bMouseTracking)
    {
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
        tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
        tme.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE;
        tme.hwndTrack = this->m_hWnd;

        if (::_TrackMouseEvent(&tme))
        {
            m_bMouseTracking = TRUE;
            AfxMessageBox("MFC Button Mouse Move");
        }
    }
    CMFCButton::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}

void CMFCButtonEx::OnMouseLeave()
{
    m_bMouseTracking = FALSE;
    AfxMessageBox("MFC Button Mouse Move");
    CMFCButton::OnMouseLeave();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE` is not triggered for `CMFCButton`, or any classes derived from `CMFCButton`

As stated in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bcn-hotitemchange), Visual Style must be enabled otherwise `BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE` is not triggered. `CMFCButton` relies on owner draw method, so visual style is disabled for this button.

You could remove `BS_OWNERDRAW` from your `CMFCButtonEx` class. But this is not recommended because `CMFCButtonEx` relies on `BS_OWNERDRAW`.

A better solution is derive your class from `CButton` (and make sure Visual Styles is enabled), use custom draw instead of owner draw. You may not need `OnMouseMove` and `OnMouseLeave`.

```
class CMyButton : public CButton {}
...

BOOL CMyButton::OnButtonItemChange(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    auto ptr = (NMBCHOTITEM*)pNMHDR;
    bool enter = ptr->dwFlags & HICF_ENTERING;
    if (enter)
        TRACE(L"CMyButton... enter\n");
    else
        TRACE(L"CMyButton... exit\n");
    *pResult = 0;
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. As I also mentioned in my question that deriving from CButton works but I have to use CMFCButton since I want to use CMFCButton::m_nFlatStyle, to set BUTTONSTYLE_3D when mouse is on the button, and BUTTONSTYLE_NOBORDERS when mouse leaves the button. I'm able to accomplish this using OnMouseMove and OnMouseLeave with TrackMouseEvent. I could not figure out why BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE notification code didn't work with CMFCButton. I guess CMFCButton will never work with that notification unless there is way to set those styles on CButton object.

Comment: If you want a flat button which becomes 3-D on hover, then put `my_mfc_button.m_nFlatStyle = CMFCButton::BUTTONSTYLE_FLAT` after `CDialog::OnInitDialog()`

Comment: Thanks for answering again. I’ve not tried m_nFlatStyle = BUTTONSTYLE_FLAT. If the flat button is going to show borders then it won't work for me. It’s like when you hover over a button a highlighted rectangle is drawn over and when you leave the button there is no border i.e the rectangle disappers. Below is what I'm doing and it works fine for my needs. I was just trying to use BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE notification instead of using both OnMouseMove and OnMouseLeave. I don't think that's possible since my class is derived from CMFCButton. Unless there is a way.

Comment: In my dialog's OnInitDiaolog() I set the m_nFlatStyle = BUTTONSTYLE_NOBORDERS. Then in OnMouseMove(), I set m_nFlatStyle= BUTTONSTYLE_3D. And in OnMouseLeave() I set it back to no borders i.e. m_nFlatStyle= BUTTONSTYLE_NOBORDERS. Like I said this does what I'm trying to achieve but then I can't use the BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE and have to use mouse notifications instead.

Comment: I will try this on Tuesday. But I have tried flat style before and it doesn't do what I want. I want no rectangle at all when no mouse is on it i.e I don't want it to look like a button. I'll probably follow the logic I explained earlier as it works fine. I just wanted to use BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE instead of mouse notifications but I see I can't.

Comment: Just to do a final update. I tried the flat button, and it doesn't do what I want as is also explained in comments above. I'm going with BUTTONSTYLE_NOBORDERS style and will change it to BUTTONSTYLE_3D in OnMouseMove and then change it back to BUTTONSTYLE_NOBORDERS in OnMouseLeave. This creates the affect I want, hence I cannot use BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE notification and have to use mouse notifications. Thanks for all the help!